# No class found LoggerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, icalendar, ical4j

I'm wanting to read an iCalendar (ics file) for a project and thinking it might be easier to just use an API. After much research I found iCal4j.

I'm new to ical4j, and have been searching for an answer, and trying to do research and found that the creator of it allows any form of logging they want, so I'm really baffled. I'm trying to get just a simple example I found working. I'm horrible with different APIs, and it kills me. I just have the iCal4j-2.0-beta1.jar in my classpath, and I have the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.data.*;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.*;

public class iCalendarSupport
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Downloads\\basic (1).ics");
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            Calendar calendar = builder.build(fin);
            System.out.println(calendar.getComponent("Event").toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output I have in the console in eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator.<clinit>(Configurator.java:51)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarParserFactory.<clinit>(CalendarParserFactory.java:63)
    at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder.<init>(CalendarBuilder.java:104)
    at iCalendarSupport.main(iCalendarSupport.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also using this tutorial to get started. (It was the most straight forward I could find. [link](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki/Tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classpath is missing the SLF4J (Simple Logging Facade) library.  You can find it here:
http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Comment: Ok, which jar is it that is needed?!?!?! There are tons of them!

Comment: I think the only ones you'd need would be slf4j-api.jar and slf4j-simple.jar.  But of course, it depends on the dependencies of iCal4j .

Comment: The dependencies in github is blocked. :-(

Now it saying:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder

How do I know what all is needed? are API's always this difficult?

Comment: You'll get the hang of it.  I find the Maven repo very useful - here is the entry for iCal4j that lists its dependencies: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j/2.0-beta1

Comment: Note that for a larger project, it's more common to use Maven to automatically resolve/download all the library dependencies, rather than doing it by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I need to look up Maven and do some research on it, maybe get used to it. But oddly enough I tried with all the compile dependencies listed and it had tons of trouble. But I found that the following JAR files worked for me: ical4j-2.0-beta1, slf4-simple-1.7.13, slf4j-api-1.7.13, commons-logging-1.2, commons-lang3-3.4.